# "Archive" doesn't appear

Tags: ios, xcode, archive

I'm trying to submit an iPhone app and "archive" is grayed out. I already went to Edit scheme and checked the box to reveal archive. This is a resubmission of an app...do I have to create a completely new profile?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the deployment target for your scheme. It can't be the simulator, it has to be a device.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you're building for "iOS Device", not for "iOS Simulator".